# ImageView in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a problem with displaying an imageView, when change to the landscape mode.

**First, I used ImageView in my layout like this.**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_des"
    android:scaleType="fitcenter"/>
```

It's working fine in both the Landscape and portrait mode. But the Imageview is not filling the layout. 
So I added layout one line to display fill image **( android:adjustViewBounds="true")**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_des"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

It's working fine in portrait, but landscape just displays a blank.

**Second, I try to use ResizableImageView.**

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (diw > 0) {
                int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            } else
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

and the layout is:

```
<com.ourteamapp.others.ResizableImageView
    android:id="@+id/imdg_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_des"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Still have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please upload image which you try to show ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use GridView and it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Main Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Image Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Source http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example